# Probability of getting distinct numbers out of two differently distributed variables.

Tags: probability, algorithms

Assume you have $X$ and $Y$.
They both take the same values, but they have different distributions, for example:

$X$, $Y$ can be: $\{1,2,3\}$

$X$ has probabilities: $\{\frac{2}{7}$ ,$\frac{2}{7}$,$\frac{3}{7}\}$

$Y$ has probabilities: $\{\frac{1}{6}$,$\frac{3}{6}$,$\frac{2}{6}\}$

Is there away to calculate the probability of getting two distinct numbers for $X$ and $Y$? i.e.  $\{12, 13, 21, 23, 31, 32\}$.

In this simple case, it's basically anything except:

11 probability $= \frac{2}{42}$

22 probability $= \frac{6}{42}$

33 probability $= \frac{6}{42}$

so the answer is: $(1- \frac{14}{42})$.

Is there away to calculate this mathematically instead of doing it exhaustively like that? or maybe a "smarter" way to achieve this algorithmically?

Cheers

Edit: Just to make this clear, obviously I'm using a very simple example and it's easy to solve it the way I did, but I can't do that when you have say 9 variables each can be from 1 to 100  inclusive.

Comment: This article about the logic of combining sample spaces may be helpful. http://www.cut-the-knot.org/Probability/SampleSpacesImportance.shtml

Comment: thanks, yes I understand that.

Comment: "$X$ has distribution $\{2,2,3\}$" would be more understandable if you said $X$ takes value $1$ with probability $\frac 27$, $2$ with probability $\frac 27$ and value $3$ with probability $\frac 37$

Answer (score 2):

I don't know any way besides going through the cases.  When you have nine variables presumably you are asking the chance that they are all distinct and you are correct there are many possibilities.  You can simplify it a bit if the chance of a match is very low by ignoring the chance of more than one match.  Then you run the same calculation as you have done above for each pair of variables out of the nine.  This means you run $\frac {9\cdot 8}2=36$ such calculations instead of a much larger number.

Comment: yeah, very interesting. It will take me some time to think about how I can use this to reduce the number of combinations I need to go through...